# Python magic function, how does it work?

Tags: python

How does this magic function work (below) i.e. `hex = '%032x' % self.int` for some reason it turns the following value...

`265631021230191344138857284998518456`

into....

`0033289ed88646a64b9fc63c808fd6b8`

```
def __str__(self):
    hex = '%032x' % self.int
    return hex
```

But all this should actually do from my knowledge is append `032x` to the end of the string `265631021230191344138857284998518456`, so whats going on? How does it do what it does?

[Full code here](https://github.com/Tamarabyte/TimeUUID/blob/master/timeUUID.py)

Comment: so you might use `%s` (s mean string)

Comment: your code converts the integer (that you have printed in decimal) into a hexadecimal string (adding 0 in front such that the length will be 32).

Comment: In this case "x" is the signed hexadecimal  conversion for string formatting operations:  https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`%x` is a [format code](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) for hex. Your function is representing a decimal value in hex.

```
>>> hex(265631021230191344138857284998518456)
'0x33289ed88646a64b9fc63c808fd6b8'
```

The full format code

```
'%032x'
```

Means represent the value in `hex` and pad it with zeros on the left until it is 32 characters wide.